# Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_CPU_ABI_INCOMPATIBLE] while building in Unity

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, build

I'm trying to build an android app with Unity and get this error in the console:

`Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_CPU_ABI_INCOMPATIBLE]`

What does it mean and how do i fix it? I followed the installation guide of the SDK and Unity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means the CPU architecture you have built does not match the CPU architecture you are trying to install the application on. For example, you built the app for ARM CPU but you are trying to run it on a x86-based host (i.e., genymotion emulator).